# the easiest way to get nested array in JSON string

Tags: php, json

```
$json_string = 'http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=marketdatav2';

$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
```

I am new in php. Maybe its stupid question. But what is the easiest way to get lastestprice of all markets?

Comment: what your json looks like, if you post it would be helpful to see and suggest.

Comment: json can be seen in the url, but it's a pretty big one

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$decoded = json_decode($jsondata);
$latestprices = array();
foreach($decoded['return']['markets'] as $val) {
    $latestprices[$val['label']] = $val['lasttradeprice'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` function to convert json string to array & traverse the array accordingly.

```
 $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
 $array = json_decode($jsondata,true);
 foreach($array['return']['markets'] as $lprice) {
  $latest_price[$lprice['label']] = $lprice['lasttradeprice'];
}
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($latest_price);
 echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: do you know how to use methods

Method: getmarkets 

Inputs: n/a 

Outputs: Array of Active Markets 


label - Name for this market
primary_currency_code - Primary currency code



this for example

Comment: @user1761818 I didn't what actually you're asking.